# Can expression using pointers causing unspecified (not undefined!) behaviour be used in constexpr context?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, constexpr, unspecified-behavior

According to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression) (emphasis mine):

> A core constant expression is any expression that does not have any
>   one of the following in any subexpression
>   (...)
>
> 7. An expression whose evaluation leads to **any form of core language
>      undefined behavior** (including signed integer overflow, division by
>      zero, pointer arithmetic outside array bounds, etc). Whether standard
>      library undefined behavior is detected is unspecified.

On the other hand there are several expressions on pointers with a result that isn't undefined but **unspecified** (cf. [[expr.rel]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.rel)) e.g.:

```
struct A {
    int v;
};

struct B {
    int v;
};

struct C: A, B {} c;

int main() {
    constexpr bool result = &c.A::v < &c.B::v;
    (void)result;
}
```

The code compiles without issues with [gcc](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/I4MIxTUIYdL8PXST) but not in [clang](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/BVpxfRgsxPgQdTJd) which states what is doubtlessly true that:

> comparison of addresses of subobjects of different base classes has unspecified

But (as I understand it) according to cppreference it should not stop compiler from compiling the code.

Which compiler is right here - gcc or clang? Am I over-interpreting cppreference?

Comment: As somebody who's too lazy to learn C++ properly... isn't it defined that the memory layout of `C` should be "first `A`, then `B`"? So it's actually almost safe to say the `result` is true (unless the instance of `C` is allocated at the end of memory wrapping around in a way where `c.B::v` is already at the beginning).

Comment: @Ped7g Actually it depends on the compiler implementation if `A::v` lays before or after `B::v`. But it could be a good to know which one is it at compile time... :)

Comment: Oh, I see, I mixed up class/struct field values allocation rules with inheritance. Need more caffeine...

Comment: @Ped7g yes an order of fields defined in a single struct would be perfectly specified

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to the catch-all case regarding UB, towards the end of the list of forbidden expressions in [expr.const] is,

> — a relational or equality operator where the result is unspecified

This also appears in cppreference list, currently numbered #19.

Comment: `The wording of the standard essentially requires the compiler to have an internal specification for all unspecified values.` Is it really a heavy requirement to demand from the compiler reproducibility?

Comment: For nonsensical code? Seems like unnecessary restrain. Remember that changing optimization can change result. So garbage results would need to stay consistent. And it's pretty hard to define all non-sense scenario resolutions.

Comment: @W.F. Maybe so, but implementation latitude is also a good thing. Undefined and unspecified behavior are just part of how the standard is specified.

Comment: @luk32 Well there are applications in which you don't really care about an order but strict relation is necessary to make algorithms efficient - e.g. partitioning. This is why I don't find the code `nonsensical`...

Comment: @W.F. I am not talking about the code. You said "*Is it really a heavy requirement to demand from the compiler reproducibility?*" Yes it is. I wasn't talking whether this one specific use-case makes sense to be unspecified rather than implementation-defined. I was just saying there are good reasons for distinction between, undefined, unspecified, and implementation defined behaviours.

Comment: @Potatoswatter well you may be your right with your diagnosis and an intention of guys from standardisation was that all expressions on pointers resulting in implementation defined result shouldn't be allowed. Let's see which is it `Clang bug, or a standard defect`.

Comment: @bogdan nice founding! seems like expressions which lead to unspecified behaviour are intended to be forbidden after all...

Comment: @bogdan Thanks, that simplifies the answer a lot :)